# How do I create an array based of values that are not in another array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

This is my Teams-Controller.rb

```
    @my_teams = current_user.teams.all
    @available_teams = Team.where.not(@my_teams.all)
  end
```

I'm trying to display all teams that the user currently has not joined. I have three models Team, TeamMember, and User. The purpose is to take the user to the show method of an available team and allow them to join the team. 
Team Model team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
end
```

User model user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, through: :team_members
end
```

Team Member model

```
class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
@my_teams = current_user.teams
@available_teams = Team.where.not(id: @my_teams.pluck(:id))
```

Basically what we want to achieve is a SQL query somehow like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams
WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: had to update my_teams.pluck to `@my_teams`, but other than that you nailed it. Thanks

Comment: hey, my pleasure :)